# Designing the game loop

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I'm developing a simple Win game. Here is my 2 similar implementations of the game loop (in c++):

approach #1:

```
while (Msg.message != WM_QUIT) {

        if (PeekMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) > 0) {
            TranslateMessage(&Msg);
            DispatchMessage(&Msg);
        }
        else {
            // Do update, rendering and all the real game loop stuff
        }
}
```

approach #2:

```
while (Msg.message != WM_QUIT) {

        if (PeekMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) > 0) {
            TranslateMessage(&Msg);
            DispatchMessage(&Msg);
        }
        
        // Do update, rendering and all the real game loop stuff
        
}}
```

My question is which one is better and which one should i choose? Is it better to do the update and rendering stuff in the else closure as in the #1 approach or just in the `while` loop block as in the #2 approach?

Comment: *What's the purpose of reading the messages* - process messages, until it exist in queue

Comment: The second loop is invariable going to build up lag. The frequency at which messages arrive is commonly (much) higher than the rendering frequency. While you may see the hardware cursor move it is only at a later time, where your code observes the input. That makes for a pretty laggy experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer entirely depends on the use-case.

In your first approach you handle any messages in the queue before you update your game status. That might spare you some updates provoked by older messages that got obsolete by more recent ones.

On a heavily loaded queue, though, this might result in your application being poorly reactive or even freezing.

The second approach avoids this by always updating the game status.

The first approach might get more robust e. g. by only allowing maximum number of messages to be processed before an update is enforced.

Comment: Sorry but You seems to be wrong - 'In your second approach you handle any messages in the queue before you update your game status' - i think that's the case i  the FIRST approach because the game updating and rendering are enclosed in the else statement...

Comment: That arose from the `while` that was there before your edit of the question – admitted, overlooked the else myself, too. Adjusted the answer.